# Position of prepositional phrases in dependent clauses; inversion in nebensatz

Tags: sentence-structure

Can a prepositional phrase be forgrounded in a dependent clause without inflicting inversion?

I know that in a nebensatz the verb comes in the final position; yet, I have become doubtful since the first two of the following sentences atleast ring grammatically correct to me as a learner.

> Was uns mehr als alles Andere betrüben kann ist, dass **in diesem
> Leben** unsere Zukunft immer ungewiss ist.
>
> Was uns mehr als alles Andere betrüben kann ist, dass unsere Zukunft,
> **in diesem Leben**, immer ungewiss ist.
>
> Was uns mehr als alles Andere betrüben kann ist, dass in diesem Leben
> **ist** unsere Zukunft immer ungewiss.

I also wonder if such disjunctive adverbial phrases should be parenthesized if they impede the flow of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text seems to be more than 100 years old, it must have been written before 1901. In modern German it would be:

> Was uns mehr als alles andere betrüben kann ist, dass in diesem Leben unsere Zukunft immer ungewiss ist.

(*andere* must be written in lowercase, *betrüben* has no h. Interesting to know: *dass* was written with *ss* before 1901 and after 1996. Between 1901 and 1996 it was *daß*)

But you asked something different:

The first two sentences are correct (in pre-1901-orthography), but the third sentence is wrong. The verb in the subordinate clause **must** be at the very end of the sentence.

btw: I don't know the pre-1901 rules for commas, but in modern German, you don't need the commas around *in diesem Leben* in sentence 2.

This are the correct German sentences:

> Was uns mehr als alles andere betrüben kann ist, dass in diesem Leben unsere Zukunft immer ungewiss ist.
>
> Was uns mehr als alles andere betrüben kann ist, dass unsere Zukunft in diesem Leben immer ungewiss ist.

Comment: Ehrelich gesagt, lese ich derzeit Romane, die mehr als 90 Jahre alt sind, denn ich meine, dass sie mir helfen Deutsch schneller und besser zu lernen. Aber, dass du sagstest meine Schreibung schient mehr als 100 Jahre alt zu sein erschreckte mich über alle Maße. :(

Comment: @user26231: Wenn du veraltetes Deutsch lernst, wird das Deutsch, das du später dann von dir gibst, veraltet sein. Ich lese selbst auch gerne alte Texte (derzeit einige Erzählungen von E.T.A. Hoffmann), weil ich diese alte Sprache mag, aber so kann man heute nicht mehr schreiben oder sprechen. Btw: Auch das Wort »betrüben« ist veraltet. Man hat dieses Wort vor 250 Jahren häufig verwendet, heute findet es kaum noch Verwendung: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=betrüben&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbetrüben%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I couldn't agree more. \m/

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other post but you would actually need another comma:

> Was uns mehr als alles andere betrüben kann**,** ist, dass in diesem
>   Leben unsere Zukunft immer ungewiss ist.
>   Was uns mehr als alles andere betrüben kann**,** ist, dass unsere Zukunft in diesem Leben immer ungewiss ist.